# Rails deployment to Heroku build failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've been deploying my app regularly to `Heroku` during development with no problems until now.

This build failed after only a couple of minor `HTML` and `CSS` changes and still appears to be functioning normally locally. I've since reverted to a previous commit that built successfully but that too results in the same error.

I've only included the topmost section of the build log but can include the rest if it's relevant.

```html
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.3.1
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.1). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
       Using rake 12.3.1
       Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
       Using minitest 5.11.3
       Using thread_safe 0.3.6
       Using builder 3.2.3
       Using erubi 1.7.1
       Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
       Using crass 1.0.4
       Using rack 2.0.4
       Using nio4r 2.3.0
       Using websocket-extensions 0.1.3
       Using mini_mime 1.0.0
       Using arel 9.0.0
       Using mimemagic 0.3.2
       Using execjs 2.7.0
       Using bcrypt 3.1.11
       Using msgpack 1.2.4
       Using popper_js 1.12.9
       Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
       Using ffi 1.9.23
       Using bundler 1.15.2
       Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
       Using method_source 0.9.0
       Using thor 0.20.0
       Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
       Using multi_json 1.13.1
       Using pg 0.20.0
       Using puma 3.11.4
       Using tilt 2.0.8
       Using i18n 1.0.1
       Using tzinfo 1.2.5
       Using rack-test 1.0.0
       Using warden 1.2.7
       Using sprockets 3.7.1
       Using websocket-driver 0.7.0
       Using mail 2.7.0
       Using marcel 0.3.2
       Using autoprefixer-rails 8.3.0
       Using uglifier 4.1.9
       Using bootsnap 1.3.0
       Using rb-inotify 0.9.10
       Using nokogiri 1.8.2
       Using coffee-script 2.4.1
       Using activesupport 5.2.0
       Using sass-listen 4.0.0
       Using globalid 0.4.1
       Using activemodel 5.2.0
       Using jbuilder 2.7.0
       Using sass 3.5.6
       Using activejob 5.2.0
       Using activerecord 5.2.0
       Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
       Using loofah 2.2.2
       Using bootstrap 4.1.0
       Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
       Using actionview 5.2.0
       Using actionpack 5.2.0
       Using actioncable 5.2.0
       Using actionmailer 5.2.0
       Using activestorage 5.2.0
       Using railties 5.2.0
       Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
       Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
       Using responders 2.4.0
       Using jquery-rails 4.3.3
       Using rails 5.2.0
       Using sass-rails 5.0.7
       Using devise 4.4.3
       Bundle complete! 24 Gemfile dependencies, 68 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
       Bundle completed (10.65s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
       Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.1). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
       The latest bundler is 1.16.1, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
       To update, run `gem install bundler`
-----> Installing node-v8.10.0-linux-x64
-----> Detecting rake tasks
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
       Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
       Asset precompilation completed (1.85s)
       Cleaning assets
       Running: rake assets:clean
sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
 !
 !     Command: 'bin/rails runner "puts %Q{heroku_detecting_active_storage_config=#{Rails.application.config.active_storage.service}}"' failed unexpectedly:
 !     /tmp/build_51f3c3aeade1d66d2890531aa58b477d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:377:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem': Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
 !     from /tmp/build_51f3c3aeade1d66d2890531aa58b477d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:12:in `<main>'

.
.
.

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: `expecting ")"` You have a missing closing brace somewhere in changes most likely.

Comment: Im not so sure you have any errors.  Purhaps this is related to current heroku issue.  I just posted this on SO...same issue you are experiencing.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49989962/heroku-push-suddenly-failing

Comment: I'll keep an eye on the status page, hopefully the error is on that end.

Comment: I'm hoping so too.  However, I am scanning through my last batch of changes for an Unterminated quoted string...which is the error I'm getting.  Strange coincidence if we both experience the same thing, and post here at the same time.  I'll update if I find a working solution...

Comment: Is heroku down for your site completely, now?

Comment: I just tried again there and the build completed. I was pushing the same commit so no idea what was causing the problem yet.

Comment: Same here.  No change on my end....but, my push just went out successful.  Moving on...  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error seems to have been caused by a change to the Heroku Ruby buildpack as described here https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/issues/744 and is now fixed.