# heroku push suddenly failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I pushed out to heroku last night, and now today my pushes are failing with the following error.  Heroku status appears to be ok.  My heroku config has RAILS_MASTER_KEY set to my master.key.  That did not help.

Any experience this...or, able to point me towards a fix?

```
Command: 'bin/rails runner "puts %Q{heroku_detecting_active_storage_config=#{Rails.application.config.active_storage.service}}"' failed unexpectedly:
remote:  !     Missing encryption key to decrypt file with. Ask your team for your master key and write it to /tmp/build_996b65d7dc5d21b59fdaad7cc82a7aba/config/master.key 
               or put it in the ENV['RAILS_MASTER_KEY'].
```

Comment: seemed to be a momentary heroku glitch.

Answer (score 1):

see : https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/pull/739, a fix seems to be merged